# Why do three of these commands not work?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm creating a custom data pack. Basically I want commands to run when the ball is within 1 block of the red marker.

These first 5 commands work great!

```
execute as @e[type=marker,name=Red] at @s if entity @e[type=armor_stand,tag=Ball,distance=..1] run particle minecraft:totem_of_undying ~ ~2 ~ 1.5 1 1.5 0 250 force
execute as @e[type=marker,name=Red] at @s if entity @e[type=armor_stand,tag=Ball,distance=..1] run playsound entity.firework_rocket.twinkle_far ambient @a ~ ~ ~ 30000 1
execute as @e[type=marker,name=Red] at @s if entity @e[type=armor_stand,tag=Ball,distance=..1] run tellraw @a {"text":"Blue DUNKED on Red!","color":"aqua","bold":true}
execute as @e[type=marker,name=Red] at @s if entity @e[type=armor_stand,tag=Ball,distance=..1] run scoreboard players add Blue Score 1
execute as @e[type=marker,name=Red] at @s if entity @e[type=armor_stand,tag=Ball,distance=..1] run tp @e[type=armor_stand,tag=Ball] -194 3 87 facing -194 4 87
```

But these last 3 don't work at all. What is going on?

```
execute as @e[type=marker,name=Red] at @s if entity @e[type=armor_stand,tag=Ball,distance=..1] run spreadplayers -193.58 75.61 3 3 true @p[team=Red]
execute as @e[type=marker,name=Red] at @s if entity @e[type=armor_stand,tag=Ball,distance=..1] run effect give @p[team=Red] minecraft:slowness 3 255 true
execute as @e[type=marker,name=Red] at @s if entity @e[type=armor_stand,tag=Ball,distance=..1] run effect give @p[team=Red] minecraft:jump_boost 15 127 true
```

Comment: This is an interesting question, but could you please expand on what exactly you mean by "not working"? Are there error messages, or do the commands work but do nothing? Also please explain what you *expect* for each of the non-working commands to do if they did work.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 By "don't work at all", I mean there is no error message, nothing happening, therefore it just doesn't do anything. Even in a command block. 

The first of the 3 commands should spread all of team red around the set coordinates.
The 2nd should keep you from moving
The 3rd should keep you from jumping

Comment: @Iceypoo Mind editing your post to include that information?

Answer (score -1):

One of the things that doesn't work that is common to all three of the failing commands you provided is the target selector `@p[team=Red]`. This means that only the *nearest* player is selected that is on the team, not all the players.

`@a` will ensure that *all* players matching the filters are selected.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! Still though, that's not the main issue, since I'm the only person on my server.